# Linking problems with GMP and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, cryptography, gmp

I am trying to run a C++ project which has also dependence to PBC (https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) and GMP (https://gmplib.org). I have installed PBC and GMP in the /usr/local/ directory. For this project I added the PBC (pbc-0.5.14) and GMP (gmp-6.1.0) libraries manually (I dragged those libraries into my project).

When I add the -lgmp -lgmpxx flags into Other linker flags in Xcode (Version 7.2) I got this:

```
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I build (and clean) without Other linker flags I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pairing_clear", referenced from:
      Member::~Member() in member.o
      Manager::~Manager() in manager.o
      Verifier::~Verifier() in verifier.o
  "_pairing_init_set_str", referenced from:
      Member::Member() in member.o
      Manager::Manager() in manager.o
      Verifier::Verifier() in verifier.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did anyone know how to fix this issue or any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 15.10(64), libgmp installed into

```
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.2.0
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.2.0
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.a
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so.4
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so.4.4.0
```

I found this using command "locate libgmp".  (locate searches what  updatedb updates.)

You say you 'installed' it locally?  I ran install without any options.   Maybe your linker is not informed about where to look for the libs?  Perhaps  add a "-L 'local location'"?

Hope this helps ...